# NextJS: __dirname is resolving to node_modules/

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack, next.js, webpack-5

I'm using a library in NextJS that make use of `__dirname` to check the current file path, but the `__dirname` is resolving to `node_modules` and not the current file calling the function.

Here a minimal example:

```
// ./node_modules/check_api/lib/index.js
function checkCurrentFile(){
  if (!__dirname.endsWith("/api")) {
     throw new Error("Not api directory");
  }

  console.error("Invalid dir: ", __dirname);
}
```

```
// ./pages/api/[hello].ts
export default handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse){
   checkCurrentFile();

   res.send("Hello");
}
```

May result in:

```sh
Error: Invalid dir: ./node_modules/check_api/lib
```

I updated my `next.config.js` to:

```js
module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  webpack5: true,
  webpack: (config) => {
    config.resolve.fallback = { __dirname: false }
    return config;
  },
};
```

Also to:

```
module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  webpack5: true,
  webpack: (config) => {
    config.target = 'node';
    config.node = {
      ...config.node,
      __dirname: true, // and false
    };
    return config;
  },
};
```

And still not working

Comment: What exactly is the problem here? I don't follow. You wrote that the file path is `.../node_modules/check_api/lib/index.js`, i.e. the directory the `index.js` resides in would be `.../node_modules/check_api/lib` - and as you also wrote, that's exactly what `__dirname` inside that file gave back. Where is the disconnect here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to solve it changing the `next.config.js`

I ended using the stacktrace for an error to check the directory name.

```js
const stackTrace = new Error().stack;
```